# maximum tcp connections for 1 instance on play framework

Tags: tcp, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm using web sockets with play framework 2.6.
What is the maximum number of connections that is possible concurrently on 1 instance.

Comment: Unless the play framework has its own low limit, the max number of tcp connections is likely a function of OS, OS configuration, hardware, hardware configuration, network throughput, expected load on the sockets, memory, etc...  So, not something we could come close to answering here with the one sentence of information you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn wrote a blog post on how they scaled their Play servers to scale to 100K connections per node:

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/10/instant-messaging-at-linkedin--scaling-to-hundreds-of-thousands-

There is no hard limit, what you'll encounter beyond that is OS imposed restrictions as described in the comments, these restrictions apply to all servers. I am aware of one person that, using a custom compiled Linux kernel, was able in a very contrived test environment to make a million connections to a single Play server node.